# How to remove English letters from Arabic text using StringToWordVector filter

Tags: java, string, filter, weka, arabic

I'm trying to use `StringToWordVector` filter on my Arabic text, and I want to remove the English letters and numbers and the emoticons "my data is tweets" and I want to keep only the Arabic words.
Does anyone know how to do this with the `StringToWordVector` filter? 
BTW, I'm using java with Weka library.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Java, so keep it simple by using simple String manipulation.

To remove Latin letters and numbers (which English uses):

```
String cleaned = input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

The definition of "emoticon" is loose, but to remove them too try:

```
String cleaned = input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]|[:;]-?[()ODp]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm gonna try this, but since I have to build the classifier on the training data set after cleaning which is from type "instances", how can I do it?